# Find the user which is getting logged out in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I need to find out the user which is getting logged out. I checked out the listener but it seems the listener is called after the user has logged out.
Basically, I need to update a column in the Users table when the user is logging out.
I have the option to override and extend the trait AuthenticatesUsers:: logout method but I want to avoid it if there is any better way to do it.
Thanks

Comment: There is user being passed to the event, check `$event->user`. Otherwise this event wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

for this problem you can add `logged_out_at` as timestamp field in your database users table and when event called update this column.